# enviar petición a una api en javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, api

estoy tratando de hacer una petición a una api que me convierte unas coordenadas en dirección, la api recibe dos parámetros: lat y lon, lo estoy tratando de hacer con ajax pero no me funciona ni me da ninguna respuesta ni errores:

este es mi ajax

```
 var url = "http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse";
          $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: url,
                                         
          data:{lat:lat,lon:lng},
          success: function(data)
           {
                                    
         var datos = JSON.parse(data);
         alert(data);
           }
       });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Según la [documentanción](https://nominatim.org/release-docs/develop/api/Reverse/) la API espera una petición GET y para que devuelva formato json debe enviarse como parámetro en la url.

```js
var url = "http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse";
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: url,
  data: { format: "json", lat: 13.856675, lon: -89.759856 },
  success: function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

no te da error, porque debes de tener un apartado para el manejo de errores en este tipo de peticiones:

```
var url = "http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse";

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: url,
  data:{lat:lat,lon:lng},
  success: function(msg){
        console.log( 'Todo bien', msg );
  },
  error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
     console.log("Algo salió mal", XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown );
  }
});
```

Con eso revisas claramente qué error recibes y podrás reaccionar.